# Алгоритм обхода полного графа через все вершины не повторяясь, с указной вершины

Tags: c#, алгоритм, консоль, графы

У нас есть полный граф, не обязательно проходить через все рёбра, нужно пройти все вершины без повторений. Как это можно реализовать на c# ?
есть такой код, но при количестве вершин равным 4 и выше зависает

```
> введите количество вершин  3
> введите начала вершины  1
> 1 лишнее
> 1-2 лишние  
> 1-2-3 
> 1-3 лишнее
> 1-3-2
```

код программы на c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
 
namespace ConsoleApp5
{
    class Edge
    {
        public int u, v;
 
        public Edge(int u, int v)
        {
            this.u = u;
            this.v = v;
        }
    }
    /* думаю как создать карту и расположить вершины графа, так что бы между ними было расстояние минимум 6 метров, и можно было менять их положение случаи чего 
    class Map
    {
        Point point = new Point(1,1);

        
        public Xmax,Ymax, colPrep;
        public Map(int Xmax=100, int Ymax=100, int colPrep=5)
        {
            int x,y;
            Random r = new Random();
            for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
            {
                x = r.Next(1, Xmax);
                y = r.Next(1, Ymax);
            }
        }

    }*/
 
    class Program
    {
 
        static bool Find(List<int> list, int x)
        {
            if (list == null) return false;
            else
            {
                foreach(var i in list)
                {
                    if (i == x) return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
 
        static bool Compare(List<int> L1,List<int> L2)
        {
            if (L1.Count == L2.Count)
            {
                for (var i = 0; i < L1.Count; i++)
                    if (L1[i] != L2[i]) return false;
            }
            else return false;
            return true;
        }
 
        static void AddWay(List<int> list, List<List<int>> listWays)
        {
            int i = 0;
            bool temp = true;
            while (i<listWays.Count&&temp)
            {   
                if (Compare(list, listWays[i])) temp = false;
                else i++;
            }
            if (temp || i == listWays.Count)
            {
                listWays.Add(new List<int>());
                foreach (var j in list)
                {
                    listWays[listWays.Count - 1].Add(j);
                }
            }
        }
 
        static void Ways(List<Edge> edges, int numberEdge, List<int> list,List<List<int>> listWays)
        {
            foreach(var edge in edges)
            {
                if(!Find(list,numberEdge))
                {
                    if (edge.u==numberEdge)
                    {
                        list.Add(numberEdge);
 
                        if (!Find(list, edge.v)) Ways(edges, edge.v, list,listWays);
                        else AddWay(list,listWays);
                        list.Remove(numberEdge);
                    }
                    else if (edge.v==numberEdge)
                    {
                        list.Add(numberEdge);
 
                        if (!Find(list, edge.u)) Ways(edges, edge.u, list, listWays);
                        else AddWay(list,listWays);
                        list.Remove(numberEdge);
                    }
                }
            }      
        }
 
        static void Print(List<int> list)
        {
            for (var i=0;i<list.Count;i++)
            {
                if (i != list.Count - 1) Console.Write($"{list[i]}-");
                else Console.Write(list[i]);
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
 
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Edge> edges = new List<Edge>();
            List<List<int>> listWays = new List<List<int>>();
            Console.WriteLine("введите количество вершин ");
            int colVer = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            if(colVer<3)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("так не работает один путь ");
            }
            int n=colVer*((colVer-1)/2);
            for (int i=1; i<=n; i++)
            {
                for(int j = 1; j<=n; j++)
                {
                    edges.Add(new Edge(i,j));
                }
            }
            /*edges.Add(new Edge(0,1));
            edges.Add(new Edge(0,2));
            edges.Add(new Edge(1,0));
            edges.Add(new Edge(2,0));*/
            Console.WriteLine("введите начала вершины ");
            int start = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Ways(edges, start, new List<int>(),listWays);
            foreach (var i in listWays) Print(i);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Самый обычный обход в ширину или глубину как раз обходит все вершины по одному разу. Главное отмечать вершины, что уже были пройдены.

Comment: *У нас есть полный граф, не обязательно проходить через все рёбра, нужно пройти все вершины без повторений* Ну так идите 1-2-3-4-...-N - без повторений, везде можно пройти (граф-то полный) - в чем проблема? Начиная с вершины M? Ну так опять же M-M+1-...-N-1-2...

Comment: путей же может быть несколько, вот их все надо вывести

Comment: Путей n! - выводите все перестановки, если n невелико

Comment: тоже так думал, но n до 20 доходит, и к примеру не выгодно будет из одного края карты в другую идти, когда есть рядом другое препятствие(вершина графа)